# I want add data in database (MS Access) by using in VB.net I used this code

Tags: vb.net

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.'

```vb
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Login").NewRow
ds.Tables("Login").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

ds.Tables("Login").Rows(r).Item(0) = txtEnNo.Text
ds.Tables("Login").Rows(r).Item(1) = txtUsername.Text
ds.Tables("Login").Rows(r).Item(2) = txtPassword.Text

da.Update(ds, "Login")
```

Comment: Your code is badly structured. Use `ds.Tables("Login")` to get the table and assign it to a variable. Call `NewRow` and assign that to a variable. Use that variable to set the fields of that row. Finally, use those two variables to add the row to the table.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a command builder, the SQL query in the `SelectCommand` of your data adapter must include one table only and the primary key column(s) of that table. It must also be known that that column(s) is the primary key.

If your table doesn't have a primary key, you need to add one. If your query doesn't include the primary key, you need to add it. You also need to set the `MissingSchemaAction` property of the data adapter to `AddWithKey`.